How do I stitch two screenshots without any overlap?
I am trying to take screenshots of a pane in a windows app without any overlap between scrolls using Python.
This is the code I have so far. When I run this, it works but there is overlap on the stitched screenshot. There are no bugs that in the code that I can tell. I have tried adjusting the height (new_image.paste(image2, (0, 273))) in an attempt to stitch correctly, but have has no luck. Also, in my research on the topic, I have not found a way to stitch the screenshots correctly. This is a bot build so I would like it to calculate the dimensions so that the user does not have to edit the dimensions manually.
def autosetup_summary_scroll():
    windows = Windows()
    autosetup= window.find_window(f'name: "AutoSetup - PathGroup - {location} - {environment} {version} - {admin} - {search_type}"')
    window_title = f"AutoSetup - PathGroup - {location} - {environment} {version} - {admin} - {search_type}"
    autosetup = window.find_window(f'name: "{window_title}"')

    app = autosetup.find_child_window('id: "1129"')
    app.click()
    app.screenshot(filename="screenshot_before_scroll.png")

    # app.ui_automation_control.GetLegacyIAccessiblePattern
    desktop.press_keys('page_down')
    #summaryscroll.update.geometry()
    app.screenshot(filename="screenshot_after_scroll.png")

    stitch_screenshots_vertically('screenshot_before_scroll.png', 'screenshot_after_scroll.png', 'stitched_screenshot.png')


def stitch_screenshots_vertically(screenshot_before_scroll, screenshot_after_scroll, stitched_screenshot):
    # Load the images
    image1 = Image.open(screenshot_before_scroll)
    image2 = Image.open(screenshot_after_scroll)

    # Calculate the total height and the maximum width
    total_height = image1.height + image2.height
    max_width = max(image1.width, image2.width)

    # Create a new blank image with the calculated size
    new_image = Image.new('RGB', (max_width, total_height))

    #update.geomerty 

    # Paste the images into the new image, one above the other
    new_image.paste(image1, (0, 0))
    new_image.paste(image2, (0, 273))

    #update.geometry

    # Save the combined image to the specified path
    new_image.save(fp="stitched_screenshot.png")


In the line new_image.paste(image2, (0, 273)), do you mean to hardcode in a value of 273? Should this not be image1.height or something similar?

My apologies, this is my first post to SO. The 273 value came from me just playing around with different values to see if it would stitch correctly. I originally had it set to image1.height, but that resulted in overlap of the screenshots. I will edit my post to include steps 3 and 4.
